# Disable iScroll and Allow Native Scrolling Again

Tags: javascript, jquery, iscroll

I have a page that has a sort of a tabbed view built into it. The middle tab uses iScroll to enable a custom "pull to refresh", however the other two tabs don't need iScroll, and I would like to allow them to have native scrolling functionality. How would I disable iScroll to let native scrolling through while not on the necessary tab?

I have tried using the `iScroll.enable(); iScroll.disable();`, and while that does what it claims to do, it does not allow native scrolling.